# Different result when using mobile than PC

Tags: javascript, html

First of all i want to thank you for spending time reading this post. I am quite new to programming and i am learning ALOT. Sorry in advance for my incompetence.

Currently working on a webapp. This app has the function to basicly access the file system, and then upload the file selected. When clicking the upload button i have created, i get different results depending on weather or not im using PC or my iPhone. 
When clicking the button on my iPhone the photo will be submitted to my storage on google cloud, but it will redirect me to the link of the picture. 
On PC it does not redirect, and it still manages to upload the picture like it should. 
I have an idea of when this problem occurs, i think it happens when submitting the form? The phone does not redirect back to the original page. 
How do i get the iPhone result to be the same as my PC, so it doesnt redirect and stay on the page of my picture.

Also, all my code is in correct tags, i just copy pasted it into this website without script tags etc, cause there is a bunch of other code irrelevant to this one i had to manuever around.

```
<form id="BilledeUpload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file"accept="image/*" name="file"class="">
<button form="BilledeUpload" name ="SendpictoDBbtn"onclick="indsaetIdb()">Upload</button>
 </form>

 function indsaetIdb(){
    let randomnummer = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999999)+1;      
    var billedenavn = document.getElementById("BilledeUpload");
    var url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/randombucketname/nottoday/"+randomnummer

    document.cookie="linket="+url;
    //document.getElementById("BilledeUpload").reset();
    console.log(findCookieBeskrivelse("linket"));

}
```

Comment: Could you open browser console(F12) and check is there any errors or warnings? And btw check onclick method in your code  there are no space between name and onclick handler if it's not a typo.

Comment: Unfortunately im not able to open the console on my phone, as this problem only happens on my phone. No typos i have quadruple checked my code at this point. It works flawless on PC just not on phone, and i have no idea why.

Comment: You can debug your phone Chrome browser via PC check this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Comment: name ="SendpictoDBbtn"onclick="indsaetIdb()" i mean this one, you should add space between 
name ="SendpictoDBbtn" onclick="indsaetIdb()"

Comment: Im using safari! But i guess theres a debug function for that aswell. 
Thank you, maybe i will find my answer when i come home and am able to debug it. 
Apparently i need a cable to connect my devices, which i do not currently have.

Comment: Where does the actual upload happen? The function you have shown us doesn’t seem to do much, it sets a few variables and a cookie. So you are uploading this to your own server first, and then from there it gets send to the cloud storage URL you transport via cookie - or what exactly is going on? Your code does not show any explicit redirect either - so presumably that happens from within your server-side code as well …?

Comment: the upload happens when submitting the form @misorude 
HTML5 works in mysterious ways. 
And when i click the button it submits it i guess.

Comment: That’s not what I meant. If you submit this to your own server first, then you must have implemented logic there that then sends this data to your cloud storage - so where is that code? Maybe what goes “wrong”, goes wrong in that part? The redirect to the “link of the picture” might originate there …

Comment: I think you're right @misorude, i havent come to creating a proper logic. It's just funny how this isnt a problem on PC, but magicly it is on phone.